# Geometry with Latex

Tags: geometry

I am a new user to Latex. How do you draw geometry with Latex? Do you have to enter code? Or there is a convenient tool that you can just drag lines and it will give you the code with your drawing? I appreciate any help. I just have no idea on this.

Comment: Tkz-euclide is the place to start if you want to draw with LaTeX. Documentation is [here](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf). [Geogrebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) is another approach.

Comment: @DJP I think it would be best to at least mention that there is no documentation available in English. (I wish this were not so as the packages look nice but, for me, they might as well not exist. I realise you can look at examples but I find it difficult enough to learn new packages when I can read the documentation, let alone when I can't!)

Comment: If you prefer a graphical tool, you can create the images in the programme of your choice, save them as PNG or PDF or JPG or whatever and include them in your document using the `graphicx` package. Or you can use Inkscape and export TiKZ code (though the code tends to be somewhat unreadable).

Comment: I do not know what TiKZ is. How do you download or use it?

Comment: You also can use the `pstricks` family of packages and especially `pst-eucl`. It consists in a sphisticated interface between LaTeX and PostScript. Can compile w pdfLaTex if you use the `pdf` options. You can see the documentations and examples here: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/